# How to use jQuery plugins with Aurelia

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, aurelia, notifyjs

How do I use jquery plugins with Aurelia? In particular, I am trying to use [Notify.js](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/).

It's in my **package.json** under **jspm** -> **dependencies** as follows:

`"notifyjs-browser": "npm:notifyjs-browser@^0.4.2"`

And I have tried to import it as follows:

`import { notify } from 'notifyjs-browser';`

And use it like so:

`$.notify("Test 123", "error");`

However, I get this error message:

`$.notify is not a function`

I assume I will have the same issue with any jQuery plugins in Aurelia. How do I solve this?

**UPDATE:** It appears that the issue may only exist when using a JSPM setup as I have, as both @peinearydevelopment's answer and another answer I received for this [same question](https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/integrating-jquery-plugins-with-aurelia/1177/5) on Aurelia's "discourse" page both insist notifyjs works fine with Aurelia CLI. It would be really great if I don't have to rewrite everything just to change from JSPM to Aurelia CLI. Can anyone help figure this out? Moving to Aurelia CLI seems like a lot of work for this small problem.

Comment: try just: import 'notifyjs-browser';

Comment: Are you using aurelia-cli or is your project based on one of the older jspm skeletons?

Comment: @RabahG `import 'notifyjs-browser'` does not work. Same error.

Comment: @FredKleuver I actually have it built from scratch using .cshtml (Razor) views, but based it on one of the old ES6 / JSPM skeletons. You can find a skeleton of my work here if you want: https://github.com/gordon-matt/aurelia-razor-netcore2-skeleton. What I am working on now is a more complex, real world app... but same basic setup as that

Comment: Migrating to CLI really shouldn't be a huge issue unless you've got loads of custom build steps. All your VM code and templates should just work the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get **Notify.js** to work under a **JSPM** setup, so I decided to find something else instead. I opted for the [aurelia-notification](https://github.com/SpoonX/aurelia-notification) plugin and that's working fine. I would still love to know what the issue is getting it to work under JSPM, because there are likely to be other libraries with the same problem. So if anyone has the answer, please do share.

Answer (score 2):

Without having your exact setup, it is hard to give you a full answer. The reason for the error you are getting is due to the fact that you haven't imported jQuery. Without that, Aurelia, or more specifically its resource loader won't pull that script into your application, hence `notify` not being a 'function' as it is an extension of the jQuery prototype.

I know it is a bit of a different setup, but here is how I got that plugin to work.
I created a new project with the Aurelia cli.

`au new au-notifyjs`

I then installed the desired packages

`au install jquery notifyjs-browser`

This will install the npm packages, update your `package.json` file and update the `aurelia.json` file with proper references to the js files as well as notify's css file.

I then updated the `app.js` file to test that it works to the following:

```
import 'jquery';
import 'notifyjs-browser';

export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello World!';
  }

  attached() {
    $.notify('Test 123', 'error');
  }
}
```

I ran the app and saw the notification appear in the upper right hand corner of the screen. Full code project can be found [here](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/au-notifyjs). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm afraid you're mistaken with regards to me not importing jQuery. I have indeed imported it and been using it for other purposes. I even have jQuery Validation plugin working fine as well. They are imported as follows and work fine: `import $ from 'jquery';` and `import { validation } from 'jquery-validation';`. Anyway, I'm not sure what the issue is here.. I do have a JSPM setup though (as opposed to the Aurelia CLI, not sure if that makes any difference)

Comment: Any idea why this wouldn't work in a JSPM setup? I may have to migrate to Aurelia CLI instead.